# Filter a MultiMap<Predicate, value>

Tags: java, filter, functional-programming, guava, predicates

Block are some long-lived instances representing types, e.g. A Minecraft BlockType grass, green_wool etc.

I'm trying to find a DataStructure that can efficiently store and test for a given BlockPattern (think like, an obsidian portal, Wither etc if you are familiar with Minecraft) but if you are not familiar, being able to create a class that can test for a given structure being built out of blocks at given Vector3i's relative to the block being placed.

The Vector3i represents an integer vector of where in a 'block pattern' that a given predicate can match to.

e.g. you could have a predicate that tests for an arbitrary block property 'hotness' that tests true for fire and lava.

So rather then scan the whole pattern each time to make sure that the block positions in the world, match the predicates, I was thinking about reversing the problem.

Cache the potential positions that a Block can be in a pattern in a multimap, and get all the potential positions, in order to limit the amount of checks that happen afterwards.

So I have a `Multimap<Predicate<Block>,Vector3i>` patternLookup cache.

Which is representing the potential positions that a block is allowed to be found in the BlockPattern.

So the player places a Block, I need to filter the Multimap, collecting all possible locations the block is 'allowed' (predicate true) to be in.

However, as an optimization step, I thought it may be faster to only test the predicates that have a potential match (in terms of identity). (3 years on I'm not sure if this assumption is true)

How can I filter the contents of the multimap to get a collection of values, using guava's functional features? (or am I better just iterating over the `EntrySet`?)

e.g.

Comment: Sure, iterate over the entrySet, but why would you be keying a `Multimap` on a `Predicate` in the first place?

Comment: I'm providing an API so another application can provide predicates to match a 3d array of voxels, by allowing them to provide predicates it lets them match whatever they need to.

I'm keying off of the provided predicates as an optimization measure, So I only need to check the vectors that match and return the results that matter. https://github.com/ryantheleach/MemoryStones-Sponge/blob/master/src/main/java/au/id/rleach/efficientmultiblocks/BlockPattern.java

Comment: Yeah, there's not going to be a much better option than iterating over the `entries()` or the `asMap().entrySet()`, depending on the output format you want.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use [`Multimaps.filterEntries()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#filterEntries-com.google.common.collect.Multimap-com.google.common.base.Predicate-), something like:

```
public static <V> Multimap<Predicate<V>, V> filterByPredicateKey(
    Multimap<Predicate<V>, V> multimap) {
  return Multimaps.filterEntries(multimap, e -> e.getKey().apply(e.getValue()));
}
```

That doesn't quite match the multimap type signature you mention in your question, but I assume `block` and `Vector3i` are related in some way, otherwise you couldn't apply the predicate to the values anyways.

This returns a view of the backing multimap, which is free (*O(1)*) to construct but applies the filtering at access time, so `.get()` on the returned multimap is *O(n)*. Depending on the expected use cases you may prefer to copy this multimap into a separate immutable multimap so the filtering only happens once.

Comment: That's filtering the map by its key applied to the value right?  It's been a few years, but what I was trying to do at the time was optimise the lookup / scanning of a large area of Minecraft blocks. Block in this case is a singleton representing a lightweight state of a block and the vector a position of where blocks where found the first time the predicate tested. So I was trying to use the identity of a side effect free predicate in order to save time scanning the same area multiple times.

Comment: So the predicates that the multimap is keyed on aren't what's being used to filter the entries? What sort of filtering were you trying to do?

Comment: I think that adding a block parameter to filterByPredicateKey and doing e.getKey().apply(block) would filter the collection only returning results where the predicate was true, and that's close to what I was asking. But it's been that long I'm not sure what I was asking.